# Is it okay to memset a struct which has an another struct with Smart pointer member?

Tags: c++, c++11

Following codeblock is compiling and running okay.

Qeus-1. Is it safe to memset a struct which contains another stuct with smart pointer as a member variable? (like the example code below)

Ques-2. Is it safe to memset a struct which contains smart pointer members?

Following code structure is part of a legacy project where this hierarchical structures have hundreds of other members (POD or non POD memebers)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <memory>


typedef struct _Globals{
  std::shared_ptr<std::map<int, std::string> > rollNamePair;
} _Globals;

struct _Class {
  struct _Globals Globals;  // global vars
};

struct _School {
  struct _Class *pSchool;
};

int main()
{
  struct _School abc;
  memset(&abc, 0, sizeof(struct _School));
  abc.pSchool= (struct _Class*) malloc(sizeof(struct _Class));
  abc.pSchool->Globals.rollNamePair= std::make_shared<std::map<int, std::string> >();
  (*abc.pSchool->Globals.rollNamePair)[1]= "John";
  (*abc.pSchool->Globals.rollNamePair)[2]= "Paul";

  std::cout << (*abc.pSchool->Globals.rollNamePair)[1] << "\n";
  std::cout << (*abc.pSchool->Globals.rollNamePair)[2];

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: No, and neither is it safe to `malloc()` a `struct` with a member with a constructor!

Comment: `_School` doesn't contain a smart pointer, it contains a raw one.

Comment: By the way, you don't need the `typedef`s and half of the `struct`s here.

Comment: @Evg, title updated

Comment: @Evg, I have updated my questions in bullet points. please share your answers/comment if you want.

Comment: Also names like `_Globals` and `_School` are reserved. Maybe you've picked it up from looking at your implementations standard library, it uses ugly names like that *because* they are reserved for it.

Comment: Technically, you can't assume that `memset(pSchool, 0, sizeof pSchool)` will make `pSchool` equal to a null pointer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, never use `memset` on any structure which is not [POD](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/PODType).

However your code isn't doing that, it is only calling `memset` on `_School` which is POD as it only contains a pointer, calling `memset` on `_Class` or `_Globals` would have undefined behaviour. However I'd prefer removing the `memset` and adding a constructor to `_School` which initialises `pSchool` to `nullptr`:

```
struct _School {
  _Class *pSchool;
  _School() : pSchool(nullptr) {}
};
```

You need to use `new` in C++ code rather than `malloc` as `malloc` doesn't call class constructors.

Also note that identifiers starting with underscore followed by an uppercase character are reserved for use by the compiler/standard library.

The complete code would be:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

struct Globals{
  std::shared_ptr<std::map<int, std::string> > rollNamePair;
};

struct Class {
  Globals Globals;  // global vars
};

struct School {
  Class *pSchool;
  School() :pSchool(nullptr) {}
};

int main()
{
  School abc;
  abc.pSchool= new Class();
  abc.pSchool->Globals.rollNamePair = std::make_shared<std::map<int, std::string> >();
  (*abc.pSchool->Globals.rollNamePair)[1] = "John";
  (*abc.pSchool->Globals.rollNamePair)[2] = "Paul";

  std::cout << (*abc.pSchool->Globals.rollNamePair)[1] << "\n";
  std::cout << (*abc.pSchool->Globals.rollNamePair)[2];

  delete abc.pSchool;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your precise answers. I have updated the question to make it more clear. But I believe your answers are still valid to my questions.
The code is replicated from a legacy C project which we are trying to convert in modern C++11

Comment: @JohnCooper I've added an answer to your second question

Answer (score 1):

To address the second question, if you have a struct

```
struct G {
    std::shared_ptr<T> ptr;
};
```

that contains a smart pointer as its member, then doing

```
G g;
std::memset(&g, 0, sizeof(G));
```

is definitely not safe, because you overwrite `g.ptr` object of a non-POD type that has already been constructed.

What you could do is something like this:

```
std::aligned_storage_t<sizeof(G), alignof(G)> storage; // Raw storage of some POD type
std::memset(&storage, 0, sizeof(G));
auto g = new (&storage) G;
g->ptr = std::make_shared ... ;
// ...
std::destroy_at(g);
```

There is no reason to use `memset` in this particular example, but it is legal and safe.